# Can the AWS Support Plan be changed via CLI/API?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Was looking to see if there was a way to use the `aws` cli to change my account's "Support Plan" from Developer to Business. The manual method through the web UI is described here, titled: [How do I change my AWS Support plan?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/change-support-plan/).

I'm just trying to understand if this is possible when setting up an account or if I have to do this manually or if it can be automated through the `aws` cli.

The `support` subcommand for `aws` doesn't appear to offer this particular feature.

#### References

- [The AWS Support API reference - support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/support/index.html)
- [About the AWS Support API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssupport/latest/user/Welcome.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to change the support plan via CLI.  My reference is that you can't prove a negative.

Even if it were possible it wouldn't be a best practice, here's why:

To change the AWS support plan requires using the root account.  This is discussed around 1:05 in the video of the link you attached https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/change-support-plan/

Your root account should not have access keys associated with the account.

> You use an access key (an access key ID and secret access key) to make programmatic requests to AWS. However, do not use your AWS account root user access key. The access key for your AWS account root user gives full access to all your resources for all AWS services, including your billing information. You cannot reduce the permissions associated with your AWS account root user access key.
>
> - If you don't already have an access key for your AWS account root user, don't create one unless you absolutely need to. Instead, use your account email address and password to sign in to the AWS Management Console and create an IAM user for yourself that has administrative permissions.
> - If you do have an access key for your AWS account root user, delete it. If you must keep it, rotate (change) the access key regularly. To delete or rotate your root user access keys, go to the My Security Credentials page in the AWS Management Console and sign in with your account's email address and password. You can manage your access keys in the Access keys section. For more information about rotating access keys, see Rotating Access Keys.

#### References

- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/change-support-plan/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#lock-away-credentials

Answer (score 0):

You don't need root, you can check with AWS CLI. This is how I've done it in the past:

```
    SUPPORT_STATUS=$(eval aws support describe-severity-levels --region us-east-1 2>&1)
    if [[ "$SUPPORT_STATUS" == *"SubscriptionRequiredException"* ]]; then
        echo "No Support Enabled for account"
    elif [[ "$SUPPORT_STATUS" == *"AccessDeniedException"* ]]; then
        echo "Access denied or roles not properly setup"
    elif [[ "$SUPPORT_STATUS" == *"critical"* ]]; then
        echo "Enterprise Support already enabled for account..."
    elif [[ "$SUPPORT_STATUS" == *"urgent"* ]]; then
        echo "Only Business Level Support enabled for account..."
    elif [[ "$SUPPORT_STATUS" == *"high"* ]]; then
        echo "Only Developer Level Support enabled for account..."
    fi
```

...also, I believe they are about to release the ability to manage support plans via API natively as https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssupport/latest/user/security-support-plans.html added only a few days ago with the following actions:

```
supportplans:GetSupportPlan
supportplans:GetSupportPlanUpdateStatus
supportplans:StartSupportPlanUpdate
```

It still hasn't hit AWS CLI and Boto though...